# Android (Java) - If i select a picture from gallery app crash

Tags: android, crash

Sry for my bad english, im from germany.
I've developing a Android App and if i select a picture from gallery is the app crash.
On old devices (4.0.2) its works fine but on galaxy s4 its not work.
in logcat i cant see logs.

my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == IMAGE_UPLOAD && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri);
        uploadItem.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    if(isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        if(isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        } else if(isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        } else if(isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    } else if("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        if(isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    } else if("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
    finally {
        if(cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat..

Comment: "in logcat i cant see logs."

Comment: Run it once more in debug mode and check if usb debugging is enabled in your device..

Comment: I have run in debug mode and the usb debbuging ist checked. i have readed in internet the problem is on new devices.